# Showmodaldialog help button in title bar

Tags: titlebar, hta, showmodaldialog

I have an HTA which opens a showmodaldialog and this JavaScript code in the dialog page:

```
function helpButton(){
     document.body.style.curosor = "help";
     my_div.onclick = function(){alert("Help for the div is displayed here")}
}
```

I want a help button in the title bar of the showmodaldialog, like on the picture below:
[image: help button]

(don't mind about the fact that the picture's in French, it's my computer's language)

When I push on that help button, I want it to execute the `helpButton()` function.

Answer (score 0):

There was `showModalDialog('path', 'arg', 'help:yes');` and you could attach an `onhelp` handler within the opened dialog's `window`. However, this dialog property is obsoleted - since IE9, if I'd recall correctly - and can't be returned by downgrading the app using `X-UA` when running a HTA with a newer IE.

You still can set `onhelp`, and call it by hitting <kbd>F1</kbd>:

```
window.onhelp = function () {
    alert('Help is asked.');
};
```

Comment: `showModalDialog("path", "arg", "help:yes")` is not working even if my computer has IE8. I tried to put in `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=6" />` and it still dosn't work. I also tried it with `ie=7` and `ie=8` with no result. As far as `window.onhelp` is concerned, I already use it for `window.open("help.html")` (opens a help HTML document). It might be useful for you to know that I'm programming in HTA.

Comment: "`... can't be returned by downgrading the app ...`". I might recall  the version incorrectly, or it was even an OS based change to Vista or  Windows7.

Comment: I can always put a `<button onclick="helpButton()">Help</button>` on the bottom of the page, but I hoped to be able to do something better.

Comment: Well, when this change occured, I added a "status" div to my dialogs and showed a short description of dialog items there using `mouseover`.